# python: No module named

Tags: python, linux, ros

I am compiling a bunch of package in a gentoo OS and while compiling I get this error.

```
execute_process(/tmp/gentoo/usr/bin/python -m rosidl_adapter --package-name
  rosidl_generator_c --arguments-file
/tmp/gentoo/var/tmp/portage/ros-galactic/rosidl_generator_c-2.2.1-r2/work/rosidl_generator_c-2.2.1_build/rosidl_adapter__arguments__rosidl_generator_c_interfaces.json
  --output-dir
/tmp/gentoo/var/tmp/portage/ros-galactic/rosidl_generator_c-2.2.1-r2/work/rosidl_generator_c-2.2.1_build/rosidl_adapter/rosidl_generator_c
  --output-file
/tmp/gentoo/var/tmp/portage/ros-galactic/rosidl_generator_c-2.2.1-r2/work/rosidl_generator_c-2.2.1_build/rosidl_adapter/rosidl_generator_c_interfaces.idls)
  returned error code 1:

/tmp/gentoo/usr/lib/python-exec/python3.8/python: No module named
  rosidl_adapter
```

From what I understand is that python simply can't find the module. Then I checked all the packages installed using

```
python3 -m pip list
```

And the package doesn't appear in this list. Is it because I didn't install it through pip ?
Also I was able to find rosidl_adapter package under another folder and added this path to the python path. Rerun the previous command to list every package but this one would print the exact same thing.

How and what do I have to modify in order for python to actually see my package.

Comment: Why are you struggling on an unsupported platform? You are better to ask one of the core maintainer, although you will not likely get a friendly response. Anyway, did you successfully install ROS? What version did you install if you succeeded?

Comment: I am using gentoo because I need to use it for my robot since I don't have root access and libraries are outdated on the robot. I didn't succeed. I am trying to compile the ros_base package for galactic and I believe this error is purely a python error.

Comment: So you are working on a legacy system. You have to port all of the packages in the dependency tree. Naming a few, ros-galactic-ros-core, ros-galactic-ament-cmake, ros-galactic-rosidl-default-runtime.

Comment: Yes, this is what I am doing and debugging everything. I already compiled the package rosidl_adapter and all the test packages prior to this step.

Comment: Then you didn't install the ros-galactic-rosidl-adapter package.

Comment: I did. In my docker file I have these 
`RUN $PREFIXED ${EMERGE_FLAG} emerge ros-galactic/rosidl_adapter
RUN ls ${EPREFIX}/opt/ros/galactic/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rosidl_adapter`
and would see this output from the latter command :

`__init__.py
__main__.py
__pycache__
action
cli.py
main.py
msg
parser.py
resource
srv`
So the files are here and the compiling step doesn't show any error or warning

Comment: With no information on your build system, I guess that you have two Python environments - one for ```/tmp/gentoo/usr/lib/python-3.8``` which seems to be related to Portage and one for ```${EPREFIX}/opt/ros/galactic/lib/python3.8```, and you should choose only one.